# Brew cannot start mysql service

Tags: mysql, service, homebrew

I have been using brew and mysql successfully on this mac os Ventura computer.  Now, when I try to start up mysql via Brew I get the following output:

```
% brew services start mysql
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/504 /Users/bmr/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` exited with 5.
```

I have tried uninstalling and then reinstalling both mysql and brew.

I have been researching a lot and nothing I find is a good fit.  Any ideas on how to get the mysql service back to running?

I was expecting

```
% brew services start mysql
mysql service started.
```

and for the service to be available to be connected to on the port specified by my configuration file.

Comment: and when I run `brew services list` I see the line
`mysql   error  19968 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`